# How can I use an Observable correctly in order to not get errors when I try to access an Object key value?

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs6

This is the component

```
export class ButtonGroupComponent implements OnInit {

@Input() items: Array<Object>;

constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
}

ngOnInit(){
    console.log('this.constructor.name ' + this.constructor.name);
    console.log(this.items);

}

onParentClick(index) {
    let items = this.items;
    Observable.of(items).subscribe(items => {
        this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(items[index].eventName, {}));
        console.log( items[index].eventName );
    });
}
```

And this is the template:

```
<custom-button  *ngFor="let el of items ; let i = index"
            type="{{el.type}}"
            btnName="{{el.btnName}}"
            btnIcon="{{el.btnIcon}}"
            disabled="{{el.disabled}}"

            (childClickEvent)="onParentClick($event)"
            [index]="i"
            [item]="item"
>
</custom-button>
```

'items' is an array of object that arrives from host of pt-button-group and describes what kind of buttons the page will have.

In order to know which button of the group have been clicked the component dispatch the index of the object that correspond to the button clicked and the description of the event name of that button.

When I compile I get twice the error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'eventName' does not exist on 
type 'Object'
```

but how is this possible? Observables are suppose to be sync right? Did I wrote that Observable wrong? How can I get the eventName value without getting errors?

Answer (score 1):

You declared `items` as array of objects, where native object does not have `eventName` property. Try with dummy casting to `any`:

```
onParentClick(index) {
    let items = this.items;
    Observable.of(items).subscribe(items => {
        this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent((items[index] as any).eventName, {}));
        console.log( (items[index] as any).eventName );
    });
}
```

After that you should not have compilation error, but you might still get run time error. If so, you must double check the actual type of property passed to this component via `@Input`, because it might be the case, those really don't have `eventName` property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast `items` with `any`:

```
onParentClick(index) {
    let items = this.items;
    Observable.of(items).subscribe((items: any) => {  //<======= here you can set any
        this.el.nativeElement.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(items[index].eventName, {}));
        console.log( items[index].eventName );
    });
}
```